# How to draw network live graphs(able to select one by clicking) using networkx and matplotlib

Tags: graph, networkx, uniqueidentifier

I just wrote this code which is below total number of row for the data is 35K

I just want to draw all edges for nodes,  and see through which data they are connected.

The main reason there is to many edges for nodes which make me curious if the data is dirty or I did something wrong.

Lets say I just want to see products with unique_key= A1 and what is their common point

|  | Product | References | Unique Key |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 155 | abc01130001 | 83120880150 | A1 |  |
| 156 | abc01130001 | 5410920905 | A1 |  |
| 157 | abc01130001 | 0000901551 | A1 |  |
| 158 | abc01130001 | A0000901551 | A1 |  |
| 159 | abc01130001 | A9060900051 | A1 |  |
| 7833 | abc01505007 | 0303561 | A100 |  |
| 7834 | abc01505007 | 71441 | A100 |  |
| 7835 | abc01505007 | 71439 | A100 |  |
| 7836 | abc01505007 | 71442 | A100 |  |
| 7837 | abc01505007 | LK086 | A100 |  |
| 7838 | abc01505007 | LK117 | A100 |  |
| 7839 | abc01505007 | 200150 | A100 |  |
| 7840 | abc01505007 | 200148 | A100 |  |
| 7841 | abc01505007 | 200151 | A100 |  |
| 7842 | abc01505008 | A5412002022 | A100 |  |

```
 import networkx as nx
    import pandas as pd
    import re
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    g = nx.Graph()
    
     df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\deneme.\Desktop\Uniqe_ID\deneme.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    
    
    
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        for r in range((len(df.columns))):
            (df.iloc[i, r]) = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', (df.iloc[i, r]))
    
    
    df = df.drop_duplicates()
    
    
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df[df['References'].duplicated(keep=False)], source='Product', target='References')
    
    products = set(df['Product'])
    G.add_nodes_from(products)  # ensure all products are in the graph
    keys = {n: f'A{i}' for i, s in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G), start=1)
            for n in s & products}
    
    df['Unique_Key'] = df['Product'].map(keys)
    
    print(df)
    
    nx.draw(g, with_labels= 'Node1')
    plt.show()
```